# Create Report to show Accounts that have Activities /No Activities Logged

Tags: reporting, account, dashboard, activities

I would like to create Dashboard /Report that displays number of Accounts that have been called /not called (activities).

For example, I have 10 Accounts and 6 of these 10 accounts have been called (activities added with subject = call). I would like to see which accounts have been called and which Accounts have not been called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If you go with two reports, one for called and one for not called you could use a cross filter on your account to filter the accounts with and without activities that meet your criteria. A simple example of cross filters can be found [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_cross_filters_create.htm).
If it needs to be one report, then I'm thinking a checkbox field on the Account that gets checked when an activity where subject = call is created would get set.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I cannot use Cross Filters as I am on Professional Edition and they are not available here. 

I cannot use a checkbox field /roll-up /workflow because Activities do not roll-up to Accounts through a Master Details relationship. Any other ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Clehan1 Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful. This info should have been provided when you asked your question to begin with.

Comment: Apologies that I did not mention this, I thought that reporting was the same with all Salesforce editions when I posted this initially. Will look at tutorial and know for next time. Thanks!

Comment: @Clehan1 I'm not too familiar with professional edition but looking around I'm not finding an easy way to accomplish this, but definitely go vote up this idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kKLNAA2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys. I have found a solution. There is a hidden field (ie. not available on the page layout) called 'LastActivityDate'. I have created a formula field on the account called: 'Has Activities' with the below formula which updates the field value to 'Yes' if it contains an activity.

IF(ISNULL( LastActivityDate ), "No", "Yes")

One thing to be aware of is that, if there is an activity present and the 'Due Date' is left blank, then it will not update the field value to 'Yes', therefore I am going to make this a required field on the Activity.

Comment: Does this cover your criteria though of Subject = Call?

Comment: Also, you wouldn't have to use up a custom field if you adopt @JennyB answer..ps. you can filter on Last Activity Date in the report, just select Last Activity Date 'not equal to' and don't enter a value in the third field.

Comment: Can you install this into your org? http://andyinthecloud.com/2015/02/16/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries-tool-dlrs-spring15-release/ then you could do a conditional rollup on activities?